# Замена текста js

Tags: javascript

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Task 6</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="gold" id="text1">
        <ul>
            <li>1~~2~~3</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
     <div class="gold" id="text1">
        <ul>
            <li>1~~2~~3</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <script>
        var listItems = document.getElementById("text1").getElementsByTagName("LI");
        for(var i = 0; i < listItems.length; i++) {
            var listItem = listItems[i];
 
            var listItemContent = listItem.textContent;
            listItem.innerHTML = listItemContent.split("~~").join("</li><li>");
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Как сделать, чтоб замена шла не только первому id? а и остальные

Comment: ид должен быть уникальным в пределах страницы

Comment: У вас два раза `id="text1"`, что есть ошибка

Comment: У меня есть одинаковые 3 новости с одинаковым id

Comment: Чтобы манипулировать элементами у них должны быть разные id

Comment: ещё раз - ид уникальный должен быть. класс у всех новостей одинаковый и вы его используете для перебора, стилизации и т.д.

Comment: и выхода из этой ситуации нет? мне нужно всего лишь изменить ~~ на <li></li> а как по классу сделать?

Comment: используйте класс - document.getElementsByClassName('gold')

Comment: var listItems = document.getElementsByClassName('gold').getElementsByTagName("LI");
        for(var i = 0; i < listItems.length; i++) {
            var listItem = listItems[i];
 
            var listItemContent = listItem.textContent;
            listItem.innerHTML = listItemContent.split("~~").join("</li><li>");
        } так?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```html
    <div class="gold" id="text1">
        <ul>
            <li>1~~2~~3</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
     <div class="gold" id="text1">
        <ul>
            <li>1~~2~~3</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <script>
        var elements = document.getElementsByClassName('gold');
       
        for(var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
            var el = elements[i].getElementsByTagName("LI");
      
            var listItemContent = el[0].textContent;
            
            
            el[0].innerHTML = listItemContent.split("~~").join("</li><li>");
        }
    </script>
```

По `id` так не получается потому что `id` должно быть уникальным. Поэтому нужно пользоваться классом например:

```
document.getElementsByClassName('имя класса');
```

Получив массив с которым мы уже можем делать что нам нужно.

**P.S:** компилятор не ругается на одинаковые `id` ,просто если он нашел первое совпадение, то остальное игнорирует.

Comment: и это работает)

Comment: А как сделать, чтоб каждая заглавная буква шла с новой строчки?

Comment: @Never3D, уточните вопрос

Answer (score 2):

```js
var goldDivs = document.querySelectorAll(".gold");

for (var j = 0; j < goldDivs.length; j++) {
  if (goldDivs[j].id == "text1") {
    var listItems = goldDivs[j].querySelectorAll("li");
    for (var i = 0; i < listItems.length; i++) {
      var listItem = listItems[i];
      var items = listItem.innerText.split("~~");
      for (var k = 0; k < items.length; k++){
        var itemChild = document.createElement("li");
        itemChild.innerText = items[k];
        listItem.parentElement.appendChild(itemChild);
      }
      listItem.parentElement.removeChild(listItem);
      
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="gold" id="text1">
  <ul>
    <li>a~~b~~c</li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div class="gold" id="text1">
  <ul>
    <li>1~~2~~3</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token }

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/n3r3hds1/ не работает(

Comment: Что не работает?

Comment: Есть текст
<li>1~~2~~3</li>
Как заменить ~~ на li и закрыть его же

Comment: <li>1</li>
<li>2</li>
<li>3</li>
Вот так должно получиться заменить по сути ~~

Comment: var listItems = document.getElementById("text1").getElementsByTagName("LI");
        for(var i = 0; i < listItems.length; i++) {
            var listItem = listItems[i];
 
            var listItemContent = listItem.textContent;
            listItem.innerHTML = listItemContent.split("~~").join("</li><li>");
        } с id работает а с классом не хочет

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/n3r3hds1/1/ не работает

Comment: идеально работает